# How I can convert this matlab code to python?

Tags: python, matlab

I have a MATLAB code that I want to translate to python. It's very simple but I don't know how to write it in python. This is the code:

```
for n=1:N
    nbefore=n-1;
    nafter=n+1;
    ynew(n)=dt*u(n)+y(n);
    unew(n)=dt*(k/m)*(y(nafter)+y(nbefore);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be careful about the indexing of `u` and `y` when using `nbefore` and `nafter` so that I don't get index out of bounds error.

Here is a Pythonic way -

```
ynew = [dt * u[i] + y[i] for i in xrange(1,n+1)]
unew = [dt * (k / m) * (y[i+1] + y[i-1]) for i in xrange(1,n+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is only part of a larger program, so I can't fill in what you don't show. But this part would be something like:

```
for n in range (1, N + 1):
    nbefore = n - 1
    nafter = n + 1
    ynew[n] = dt * u[n] + y[n]
    unew[n] = dt * (k / m) * (y[nafter] + y[nbefore])
```